# Creating custom sencha-touch js with only required modules

Tags: compilation, sencha-touch, customization

I'm working with in a Sencha Touch app project. Currently we are using `sencha-touch-all.js`. But it's size is too big. Are there any procedure to make one custom `sencha-touch.js` with only required modules.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let me know my answer helped you or not

Answer (score 0):

Mitchell Simoens says:

You can use sencha-touch-debug.js for development and if you are using MVC then you can do a build that will include only the ST classes and your application classes making it only what you need.

[Source](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?193682-Decrease-sencha-touch-all.js-file-size)

Answer (score 0):

Use the sencha cmd to generate the app, then compile with sencha app build package|production. CMD will create a bundle app.js which includes only the required clases for your app.